# How to check out from tfs on a new machine

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

my machine died. I need to download the source to a new machine. I cannot access the old workspace on the new machine.  There is *no* source on this new machine. I need to grab it from TFS 2010 basic.

What do I do??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you will not be able to access the old workspace on your new machine even when you do get a connection. You will be able to download any changes that you had checked in but not changes that you had made and not checked in.

You will need to connect to your TFS server from Visual Studio on your new machine. From the Team menu item select "Connect to Team Foundation Server..." and then connect to your TFS server. At that point you should be able to get latest like you had on your old box.